# How can water waves be transverse when we know that transverse waves are not possible in fluids?

Tags: waves

It is said that fluid cannot sustain shear stress so a transverse wave cannot exist in fluids. Well, isn't this contradictory to what see we everyday in the form of water waves?

Comment: Well, water waves are not _in_ a fluid... They live on the surface.

Comment: have a look at this http://www.acs.psu.edu/drussell/demos/waves/wavemotion.html